# Positioning multiple nested divs relative to each other

Tags: css

I have an outer div, divs inside the outer div and divs inside these divs too. I want to position the innermost div wrt to its parent, the middle level div wrt to its parent i.e. outermost div. For just divs inside a div we ca achieve this using relative positioning for the parent div and absolute positioning for child divs. But how do we achieve it when we have more levels of nested divs?

I want to have predefined width for the innermost level divs and the other higher level divs should have their width and height to just fit their child divs. I have the following code, but it does not seem to work. The code is shown below:

```
<div class='list' id='list1' style='padding: 1px; border : 5px groove; position: relative; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
<div class='tuple tuple1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; position: absolute; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
    <div class='elmnt' id='elmnt1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 6px; width: 100px;' >adasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt2' id='elmnt2' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 112px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >asdasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt3' id='elmnt3' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 218px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >asdasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt4' id='elmnt4' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 324px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class='tuple tuple2' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; position: absolute; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
    <div class='elmnt' id='elmnt1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 6px; width: 100px;' >adasd</div>
            <div class='elmnt elmnt2' id='elmnt6' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 112px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >asdasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt3' id='elmnt7' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 218px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >asdasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt4' id='elmnt8' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 324px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class='tuple tuple3' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; position: absolute; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
    <div class='elmnt' id='elmnt1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 6px; width: 100px;' >adasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt2' id='elmnt10' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 112px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >asdasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt3' id='elmnt11' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 218px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >asdasd</div>
    <div class='elmnt elmnt4' id='elmnt12' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 324px; top: 2px; width: 100px;' >sadasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problems do you run into?

Comment: Have a look at the edits in the question and the code

Comment: Hm, but if you don't know beforehand what sizes the innermost divs will be, does it still make sense to have them positioned absolutely?

Comment: The sizes of the innermost divs are known before hand.

Comment: Then you can just set the heights of the enclosing divs explicitly.

Comment: The height of the innermost divs are not known, just the widths are known.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve actually. In your example, the three second-level divs are all displayed in the exact same position (0,0). Is that by design? Anyway, I believe you might be better off if you give up on the position:absolute idea and use floats.

Answer (score 6):

Set the outermost parent to `position: relative`, and then the inner divs of all levels to `position: absolute;`

You can position an absolute element in relation to an absolute parent, so no problem there.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/dzkAF

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.one {position: relative; background: red; width: 200px; height: 200px;}

.two {position: absolute; background: blue; width: 80px; height: 80px; top: 20px; left: 30px;}

.three {position: absolute; background: green; width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 10px; left: 50px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example with no heights set but with content added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.one {position: relative; background: red; width: 200px;}

.two {position: absolute; background: blue; width: 300px; top: 20px; left: 30px;}

.three {position: absolute; background: green; width: 400px; top: 10px; left: 50px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="one">
    Some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content
    <div class="two">
    Some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content
        <div class="three">
        Some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does not seem to work. please have a look at the code i have added in the question

Comment: Your example is not very good for illustrating the issue, as most elements have no height, so you can't really see how it works. I've posted example code of what I mean so that you can see it clearly in action.

Comment: For my case the heights of the divs are not known before hand, what can be done in this case?

Comment: If they are going to get populated by content, it doesn't really matter, as the content will give them heights. The important question is where you want them to be inrelation to each other.

Comment: The innermost divs are placed horizontally using left positioning. Also, did you try viewing my code in a browser, everything just collapses, and I ave no idea why.

Comment: I explained why: it's because there is no content in your divs yet, so they have no height, so you can't see that the positioning is working. I have added another example with no heights set but with content added. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/efipI

Comment: All my innermost divs do have contents if you look carefully

Comment: Yes. Do look at my code, though, as you've missed a critical element in your code: once you've set `position: absolute;` you then need to set some position. For example, `left: 20px; top: 60px`. If you don't set a position like that, the element will just sit in the top left corner. Maybe that's the confusion. As I say, the clues are all in my code.

Comment: Yes I see that, but when you do not know the height of the divs beforehand, the the middle level divs are palced one below the other, so how can we specify the top position?

Comment: I dont think you get the point. The inner most level divs are to be placed horizantally, so they can be placed using left positioning as the width of the divs are known. 
But the middle level divs (which contain the innermost divs) are to be placed one below the other, using top positioning, but how do we set the top position when the height of the divs are not known?

Comment: Of course, you can choose a value by setting `top: Xpx` in your styles. Are you saying that you want this top position to vary depending on the height of the div? If so, you might need JS to first determine the resulting height of the parent div. But if you always want the child, say, 10px from the top of the parent, there's no problem just setting that in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy question. Can you use unordered lists nested together instead?

If you set it within a parent container, that parent can be sized and positioned absolutely if that is required for the rest of your page, but you can float the line items that you want to position horizontally and not float the ones that you want to line up vertically. Just remember that floated items need to have position:relative and a width specified.

```
<div id="parentContainer">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 1</li>
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 2</li>
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 3
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>subitem a</li>
        <li>subitem b</li>
    </ul></li>
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I find this is easier to read and maintain than a bunch of nested div tags, as well as being more semantically correct.