# Position element inside position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements, `#app`, `#main-section` that is inside `#app`, and `#magazine-detail` that is inside `#main-section`. 
How can I position `#magazine-detail` inside of `#magazine-section` when the `#app` is set to position: relative; and `#magazine-detail` is set to position: absolute;?

This is the css:

```
#app {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 77px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Entire html is too big so I am posting just a short version, hope you will get the picture:

```
<div id="app">

   ...
    <div id="main-section">
        ...
        <div id="main-section">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

I need to position `#magazine-detail 30px` from the bottom of the `main section`.
I have tried to position it with position: absolute like it is suggested to do,like this:

```
#magazine-detail {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

But then the element was position somehow 30px from the top and not bottom?

Comment: Please specify what you want to achieve - what you're doing, what should be the outcome, what is not expected outcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positioning multiple nested divs relative to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809076/positioning-multiple-nested-divs-relative-to-each-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess following is yout html

```
<div id="app">  
    <div id="main-section">  
      <div id="magazine-detail"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `#app` is relative and `main-section` is absolute with respect to `app`. The thing is that in css if you set `magazine-detail` absolute too, it will be positioned with respect to `main-section`.

Below is a working sample:

```css
#app {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;  
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#main-section {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 5px;  
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px

}
#magazine-detail {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted green;      
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="main-section">
    <div id="magazine-detail"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#app {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}

#main-section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 77px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#magazine-detail {
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  width:400px;
  bottom:30px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="app">  
    <div id="main-section">  
      <div id="magazine-detail">
      This is the test<br>
        This is the test<br>
        This is the test<br>
        This is the test<br>
        This is the test
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The position absolute position's the elements as per the parent container's position, so in order to make your **#main-section** and **#magazine-detail** *position absolute*, the **#app** should be *positioned relative*.